# Mapping an enumeration to class with a property of the same enumeration type

Tags: c#, automapper

Say I have a class with the following definition:

```
public class DestinationOuter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<DestinationInner> Siblings { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationInner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RelationEnum Relation { get; set; }
}
```

And say I have a source type:

```
public class SourceSiblings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RelationEnum Relation { get; set; }
}
```

With AutoMapper I can easily create a configuration that maps from `SourceSiblings` to `DestinationInner`, which let's me do a mapping like so:

```
SourceSiblings[] brothers = { ... };
DestinationOuter dest = new DestinationOuter();

Mapper.Map(brothers, dest.Siblings);
```

But what I'd like to be able to do is map directly from `SourceSiblings` to `DestinationOuter`. In this case, the Name and Age properties in `DestinationOuter` would be ignored in the mapping, but the idea is that `SourceSiblings` would be mapped onto `DestinationOuter.Siblings`. Using the object declarations above, I'd like to be able to do:

```
Mapper.Map(brothers, dest);
```

I'm not sure how to get this to work. I can setup the configuration like so:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<SourceSiblings>, DestinationOuter>();
```

But that doesn't do anything. It seems like I need to be able to say something like:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<SourceSiblings>, DestinationOuter>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Siblings,
                  opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

And while the above compiles, `Mapper.Map` does not actually map the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work for me, but it's pretty much what you said doesn't do anything.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SourceSiblings[] brothers = {
                                        new SourceSiblings {Name = "A", Relation = 1},
                                        new SourceSiblings {Name = "B", Relation = 2}
                                    };
        var dest = new DestinationOuter();

        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceSiblings, DestinationInner>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<SourceSiblings>, DestinationOuter>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.Age, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.Siblings, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s));

        Mapper.Map(brothers, dest);
        Console.Write(dest.Siblings.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class DestinationOuter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<DestinationInner> Siblings { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationInner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Relation { get; set; }
}

public class SourceSiblings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Relation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you are saying after the `Mapper.Map` call that `dest.Siblings` contains no records, right?

Comment: No, on the contrary. dest.Siblings is fully populated.

Comment: Arg, works for me now... my problem was that in `DestinationOuter` I had the `Siblings` List as a read-only property. Urg. Thanks for your help and taking the time to show that my theory was sound, that it should work.